# How to get certified copies of Canadian ID documents while abroad?

Tags: canada, citizenship, paperwork

I am trying to apply for Canadian citizenship for my Bolivian adopted daughter. The first step is to prove the Canadian citizenship of the parents and they ask for certified copies of ID and proof of Canadian citizenship. How can I get these certified copies while we are still abroad in Bolivia? Does it need to be done in Canada? can it be done at the embassy? I thought I could just go to a notary public here but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: Have you reviewed the information contained in [this Canada Immigration page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/certified-true-copies.html)?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica is the information on that page actually helpful?  The tool headed "How to get certified true copies of your passport" includes the question "Where in Canada are you applying from? (required)," which leads directly to this question (in the logical sense only, of course; there isn't actually a link!).

Comment: The OP's question suggested they were stuck about what to do, and I thought the "contact us" link might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **Notarial services** of an canadian Consulate or Embassy in your area.

Sample:

- [Notarial services - Government of Canada services and information in Berlin, Germany](https://www.international.gc.ca/country-pays/germany-allemagne/berlin-info.aspx?lang=eng#NS): Certifying a true copy of a document. The fee shown is per copy. CAD $20

---

- [Information by country and territory](https://www.international.gc.ca/world-monde/country-pays/index.aspx?lang=eng&_ga=2.221544024.1998945049.1646803516-1032819298.1646803516)

  - Bolivia leads to: [Embassy of Canada to Peru](https://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/peru-perou/index.aspx?lang=eng)

    - Services for Canadians